# Javascript function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, feed

Its a bit strange. I am making a bitly api call and it returns undefined for all the calls, but if I add an alert() right before I get the link variable, it returns the correct link.

Now if I add the alert here :

```
function getBitlyLink(){
    alert(bitlyLink);
    return bitlyLink;
}
```

I get the correct links and not undefined. What exactly is that alert box doing??

Comment: the alert box induces a delay . You need to use a callback

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not being executed synchronously. Pass a callback to your `getBitlyLink()` function.

Comment: which would be like function getBitlyLink(callback)?? and then callback(bitlyLink); ? How do I make the call to it then?